# JAXB maven plugin not generating classes

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, xjc

I am trying to generate the java files from the XSD, but the below code doesn't generate. If I uncomment outputDirectory, it works but delete the folder first. adding `clearOutputDir = false` is also not generating anything.

```xml
<build>
        <plugins>
            <!-- JAXB xjc plugin that invokes the xjc compiler to compile XML schema into Java classes.-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- The package in which the source files will be generated. -->
                    <packageName>uk.co.infogen.camel.message</packageName>
                    <!-- The schema directory or xsd files. -->
                    <sources>
                        <source>${basedir}/src/main/resources/xsd</source>
                    </sources>
                    <!-- The working directory to create the generated java source files. -->
                    <!--<outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                    <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>-->
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I am getting the message:

```
[INFO] --- jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.2:xjc (default) @ service-business ---
[INFO] Ignored given or default xjbSources [/Users/aaa/development/workspace/infogen/infogen_example/service-business/src/main/xjb], since it is not an existent file or directory.
[INFO] No changes detected in schema or binding files - skipping JAXB generation.
```

Comment: You should never generate to your source folder, but to target/generated-sources/xjc

Comment: yes thats why I commented outputDirectory, but it is not generating the source and giving the same info message.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The first thing is that you should **never, ever,** generate code inside `src/main/java`. Generated code should not be version-controlled and can be deleted at any-time since it will be regenerated anyway.

Generated code should always be located under `target`, the build directory of Maven. The [`jaxb2-maven-plugin`](http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.2/) will generate classes by default under [`target/generated-sources/jaxb`](http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.2/xjc-mojo.html#outputDirectory) and there's really no reason to change that. If you're using Eclipse, you just need to add this folder to the buildpath by right-clicking it and selecting "Build Path > Use a Source Folder".

When running Maven, you will run it with `mvn clean install`: it will clean the `target` folder and regenerate everything from scratch: this leads to a safe and maintainable build. You'll find that this will solve your problem: since the generated classes are deleted before the build, they will be correctly re-generated during the next build.

Of course, if this generation process is long and you don't want to do it each time, you can run Maven with just `mvn install` and configure the plugin not to remove the previously generated classes by setting [`clearOutputDir`](http://www.mojohaus.org/jaxb2-maven-plugin/Documentation/v2.2/xjc-mojo.html#clearOutputDir) to `false`. But do note that, while the build will be slightly faster, you may not detect subsequent errors in your XSD if they are updated.

Comment: I was using mvn compile to generate it, but the same code worked after trying mvn clean compile.

Comment: @krmanish007 Do remember my warning though: generating code inside `src/main/java` will only lead to pain and suffering for you! :)

Comment: thats why it was commented from the beginning. I only added to see, if that helps to generate it, and commented it again.