# How to generate Java classes from WSDL with jaxb2-maven-plugin 2.x?

Tags: java, web-services, maven, soap, wsdl

I am trying using the pluggin `jaxb2-maven-plugin` to create the Java class from the wsdl.

With the version 1.5 this code from [Generate classes with jaxb2-maven-plugin from WSDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15903249/generate-classes-with-jaxb2-maven-plugin-from-wsdl) works:

```
        <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>xjc</id>
                        <goals><goal>xjc</goal></goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <!-- Package to store the generated file -->
                    <packageName>com.example.demo.wsdl</packageName>
                    <!-- Treat the input as WSDL -->
                    <wsdl>true</wsdl>
                    <!-- Input is not XML schema -->
                    <xmlschema>false</xmlschema>
                    <!-- The WSDL file that you saved earlier -->
                    <schemaFiles>horarios.wsdl</schemaFiles>
                    <!-- The location of the WSDL file -->
                    <schemaDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</schemaDirectory>
                    <!-- The output directory to store the generated Java files -->
                    <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                    <!-- Don't clear output directory on each run -->
                    <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

But when use plugin version 2.3.1, I get this error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:jaxb2-maven-plugin:2.3.1:xjc (xjc) on project demo: MojoExecutionException: NoSchemasException -> [Help 1]
```

Does someone know how use WSDL file with this new plugin version?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have already found the solution.

When the jaxb2-maven-plugin version is >= 2.0 you have to use the follow configuration:

```
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>xjc</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <packageName>com.example.demo.wsdl</packageName>
                    <sourceType>wsdl</sourceType>
                    <sources>
                        <source>src/main/resources/horarios.wsdl</source>
                    </sources>
                    <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/</outputDirectory>
                    <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

The difference is not only the syntax. That version does not create the class within the project (src/main/java), it creates in the directory that you wrote in `outputDirectory` and in the package of `packageName`.

When you use the class generated it is transparent like if it would be in the same project.

Comment: More information related: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35242941/jaxb-maven-plugin-not-generating-classes

Answer (score 0):

If you want to begin with a XSD:

```
              <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>xjc</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xjc</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>

                <configuration>
                    <xjbSources>
                        <xjbSource>src/main/resources/global.xjb</xjbSource>
                    </xjbSources>
                    <sources>
                        <source>src/main/resources/Ventas.xsd</source>
                    </sources>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java</outputDirectory>
                    <clearOutputDir>false</clearOutputDir>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```